# How to connect Hyperledger smart contract to python script

Tags: python, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, smartcontracts

I am setting up a smart contract that has inputs to a python function and returns the result of that function. How do I connect the function to Hyperledger composer?

I've tried writing the function out into Hyperledger composer but it uses modules (pandas, numpy, pulp,...) that I can't translate. I want a transaction to invoke the python function and return the answer back as the update to the asset.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use hyperledger composer rest server

Comment: Do you know any tutorials? I dont know where to find that

Comment: Check this tutorial for the hyperledger composer rest api's https://medium.freecodecamp.org/ultimate-end-to-end-tutorial-to-create-an-application-on-blockchain-using-hyperledger-3a83a80cbc71

Answer (score 0):

You can use hyperledger composer rest server for interacting with hyperledger deployed network. Some of the tutorials is found in https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/integrating/getting-started-rest-api . Hope it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try to import the `child_process` module and then use something like `spawnSync` to execute your Python script and collect the output from the process. See https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html for the module documentation.

I haven't tried this in a transaction processor function but I reckon it is probably not recommended to run Python scripts in transaction processor functions.